# Denim jacket shoulder too wide - fix without going to a tailor?

Tags: clothing

I learned that fixing shoulder fit is the most difficult and is usually done by cutting the sleeves off and re-attach them by an experienced tailor.

I have a denim jacket and the shoulder of the jacket is 1.5 inches too wide on each side, what can I do to fix the fit without going to a tailor and perferably without a sewing machine and needle work?

Comment: How good are you with scissors, needle and thread?

Comment: @Stephie Not good, but I'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My **hack** without any sewing. This wouldn't work for a shirt, but worth trying with a jacket.

***Lateral thinking . . .*** instead of making the jacket narrower, make your shoulders wider to fit the jacket. Indirectly, by fitting shoulder pads inside the jacket.

Buy some shoulder pads, and fix them inside the jacket's shoulders with a latex adhesive such as Copydex (no affiliation).

The advantage of this brand is that it remains flexible, and the pads can be removed by gently peeling. If there is any remaining adhesive just press a small area of cotton fabric onto it. One disadvantage is the initial slight fishy smell, which soon goes.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I think shoulder pads would make the jacket look much better on me. I did some research on shoulder pads but I'm not sure what kind of pads to buy (how long? what style? Raglan?) and where to buy them. Could you offer some suggestion please?

Comment: No idea about the shopping, but I suggest you pin them in place before committing to gluing them.